# Custom ProgressBar manage different UI operations with Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-progressbar

I would like to apply two operations on my progressBar one after the other. This progressBar is displayed in a custom dialog.

First I have a state in progress where the current time is displayed in an editText over my progressBar and then I want to manage a second state where my progress bar is full but where the time in excess is displayed through this editText over my progressBar.

- State in progress:
  [image]
- State progressBar full:
  [image]

Here my code:

```
        // Define custom progress bar style
        final float[] roundedCorners = new float[]{27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27};

        pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null, null));
        pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#56d2c2"));

        progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

        mProgress.setProgressDrawable(progress);

        // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                mProgressFull = defineValueFull();

                // Operation in progress: display time flow
                while (mProgressStatus < 100) {

                    mProgressStatus = doProgress();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Update the progress bar
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

                            mCurrentTimeProgressBar.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentTime));
                            mMaxTimeProgressBar.setText(String.valueOf(mProgressFull) + " mins");
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (mProgressStatus >= 101) {
                    pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));// set progress bar in red

                    // Operation ended: display time in excess
                    while (mProgressStatus >= 101) {

                        mProgressStatus = doProgress();

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Update the progress bar
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

                                int timeExcess = mCurrentTime - mProgressFull;
                                mCurrentTimeExcessProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mCurrentTimeExcessProgressBar.setText("(+ " + Helpers.minutesRefactor(timeExcess) + ")");

                                mMaxTimeProgressBar.setText(String.valueOf(mProgressFull) + " mins");
                                mCurrentTimeProgressBar.setText(String.valueOf(mProgressFull + timeExcess));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

My problem is I can't manage on the UI these both state I mean when my progressBar is full and I want to display the red progressBar with the time in excess, I have to close my custom dialog where my progress bar is set and open a new time to update the progressBar.

How can I avoid that, and keep my progressBar continually updated and be able to change its state as I tried to define by code. I'm also wondering what is the best practice in this case, may I use two different thread for these two states ? I already tried it but I didnt manage to start these wo thread one after this other and be able to update my progressBar between my two states without closing my dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will paste a code, from my project, which is very similar to this. And also notice that I didn't use a thread. Using Handle is enough. Hope this code will be helpful.

```
public abstract class ProgressView extends RelativeLayout {
protected View rootLayout;
protected TextView titleTextView;
protected SeekBar seekBar;
protected TextView secondTextView;
protected View secondLayout;

protected int initialTime;
protected int maxTime;
protected long timerStartTime;
protected int currentTime;


public ProgressView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public ProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public ProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.progress_view, this);
    rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
    titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    secondTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondTextView);
    secondLayout = findViewById(R.id.secondLayout);
    updateTime();
}

public void startTimer(int current, int max) {
    if(getVisibility() != VISIBLE) {
        this.initialTime = current;
        this.maxTime = max;
        this.timerStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        updateTime();
        post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateTime();
                if(currentTime > 0) {
                    post(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

protected void updateTime() {
    currentTime = (int) (initialTime - (System.currentTimeMillis() - timerStartTime));
    secondTextView.setText(Integer.toString(Math.round(currentTime / 1000.0f)));
    seekBar.setProgress((int) (10000.0f * currentTime / maxTime));
    if(currentTime <= 0 || currentTime > maxTime) {
        titleTextView.setText("No More Bets");
        secondLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
        seekBar.setVisibility(GONE);
        rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bet_progress_no_more_bets);
    }
    else {
        titleTextView.setText("Please, Place Your Bets");
        secondLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        seekBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bet_progress_18_sec);
    }
}
```

}

progress_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:text="Please, Place Your Bets"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleTextView"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:thumb="@null"
    android:max="10000"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@id/seekBar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sec"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I tried to use just an Handler instead of my Thread. The good point is it seems to be better in terms of performance but also I have my switch between my 2 states. The only problem for the moment is the color background which is no more loaded so I have to figure out why. So my initial problem is not totally fix yet.

Comment: So I found my mistake it was because of me. Your code definitely helped me a lot, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Did you solve background issue? If not, update the code, that I can see the full class